# Problems Understanding Haskell pure and <$>

Tags: haskell

I was just trying out some simple Haskell codes after learning Applicative and Monad, and was confused by the application of `pure` and `<$>`. I do understand the definitions, but in some special cases they seem to be mix up a little bit.

Say, I wish to get a function `foo`, which takes a `Maybe Int` and a `Maybe [Int]`, and concat the first argument to the second one. A typical definition could be:

```
foo :: Maybe Int -> Maybe [Int] -> Maybe [Int]
foo ma mb = (:) <$> ma <*> mb
```

so that `foo (Just 1) (Just [2])` would give `Just [1,2]`.

But it seems `pure` makes no sense in this case, no matter how hard I tried to make the `(:)` an applicative one. Furthermore, `pure (:) (Just 1)` works in the exactly same manner as `(:)` does, but how could it be? I suppose `(:)` takes two arguments, so the previous one should be an applicative curried function?

Thank you so much!

Comment: `<$>` aka `fmap` lifts a "pure" function into the functor, so there's no need to use `pure` as that also lifts a value into the functor. In fact you could have written `foo ma mb = pure (:) <*> ma <*> mb` had you wanted, since `f <$> x` is always equal to `pure f <*> x`. Note also that your type signature makes no sense: `Just` is a value constructor, the type constructor is `Maybe`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Furthermore, `pure (:) (Just 1)` works in the exactly same manner as `(:)` does, but how could it be?

Because of polymorphism and instance resolution. We have that

```
pure (:) :: Applicative f => f (a -> [a] -> [a])
```

Note how this works for *any* applicative `f`, not only for `Maybe`.

Then we *apply* it to `(Just 1)` which (after defaulting) has type, say, `Maybe Int`. So, to type check everything we need

```
pure (:) :: Maybe Int -> result
```

for some `result` type. We can write the above as

```
pure (:) :: (->) (Maybe Int) result
```

We then try to infer what `f` is, searching for a solution of

```
f (a -> [a] -> [a]) ~ (->) (Maybe Int) result
```

ergo,

```
f ~ (->) (Maybe Int)
(a -> [a] -> [a]) ~ result
```

Since `(->) (Maybe Int)` is an applicative, we accept this `f`. We then get

```
pure (:) (Just 1) :: a -> [a] -> [a]    -- AKA result
```

Now, what is `pure` in the `(->) (Maybe Int)` applicative?

```
instance Applicative ((->) b) where
   pure x = \_ -> x
   -- ...
```

So, `pure` simply discards the second `Just 1` argument and returns the first one `(:)`.

Concluding: the issue is that `pure (:)` does not have to work on the applicative you had in mind, `Maybe`, but is more general and will search for any applicative that makes the code to type check. If you apply `pure (:)` to something, the `(->) b` instance gets selected, and the second argument discarded.

There is a big difference from `pure f y` (which is equivalent to `f`) and `pure f <*> y` (which is equivalent to `f <$> y`).

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer really made it more clear to me!